# Is there a way to disconnect an Apple Remote Desktop observer?

Tags: macos, mac, remote-desktop

Most of the macs in our network can be controlled by Apple Remote Desktop. And sometimes people forget to close the application after being done. The macs are kind of slow, so just having someone in observe mode can make things a bit more sluggish than it usually is.

I can see up in the status bar that someone is currently Observing... but is there a way to disconnect them?

Answer (score 2):

`sudo killall AppleVNCServer` will kill observation for anyone. The Remote Management daemon will restart AppleVNCServer the next time someone wants to observe or control the computer.

Comment: This did kill the connection, but seems like Remote Desktop reconnects if the connection is dropped. Cause all I got was a short blink and then Remote Desktop was observing again.

Comment: @Svish: I had the same result but only if I was using the "-HUP" flag. Killing it killed it just fine.

Comment: I wasn't using any flags. Just `killall AppleVNCServer`. Is it using that `-HUP` thing by default or something? How do I not use that?

Answer (score 1):

File a ticket with your tech staff to be less lazy about killing ARD sessions when they're done, and also ask if they can enable the "Disconnect Observer" function that should exist in the ARD menu item when someone is observing.

Comment: Haha, will do :p